# Не работает кнопка, создаваемая скриптом

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть скрипт, копирующий префаб с небольшим окошком (Image), в котором находится кнопка, на Canvas:

```
editWindow = Instantiate(instance.editWindowPrefab, GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform);
```

Всё отлично работает кроме кнопки. Она не реагирует на нажатия. Но если её достать из окошка, и перенести напрямую в Canvas, то она заработает.

Comment: во-первых, вы указали слишком мало подробностей

Comment: а во-вторых, вы скорее всего навесили действия при нажатии на Экземпляр кнопки а не на сам Префаб

Comment: KuzCode, Повесил действие на префаб.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что кнопку перекрывал другой невидимый объект.